# Three CTE Questions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
WITH Hello (Name)
AS (
INSERT INTO MyTest
OUTPUT 
  inserted.Name
VALUES ('George')
)
SELECT * FROM Hello
```

In short, I was hoping the output would simply become the CTE input.  Is there a way to fix this?

Two more questions:

1. Is there a way to construct an empty CTE?
2. Can a CTE be modified?  Can I insert rows after it has been constructed?

**UPDATE** 
I found the answer to my primary question, with the intent of filling a CTE with arbitrary data:

```
;WITH stuff AS (
  SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
   (123, 1),
   (234, 1),
   (345, 0)
  ) [X](id, pref)
)
SELECT * FROM stuff
```

Comment: You should really ask one question per question here.

Comment: What would be the point of an empty CTE?

Comment: Remember the **E** in **CTE** stands for "expression" (not "statement") - you're not allowed to do anything except `SELECT` in the query expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the two other questions

1)

```
WITH Hello 
AS (
select  name
from sysobjects where 1 =0
)
SELECT * FROM Hello --no rows
```

2)

```
-- ***  update  ***

create table testNow(id int)
insert testNow values(1)

;WITH Hello 
AS (select id from testNow)

update Hello set id = 2 -- update cte

SELECT * FROM testNow --table now has value 2

-- ***  insert   ***

;WITH Hello 
AS (
select id from testNow

)

insert Hello values( 3 )

SELECT * FROM testNow --table now has 2 rows
```

Comment: Your answer, together with the update I made to my question - completes the answer.  Thanks.